# is it possible to subscribe observable in other tab browser with rxjs angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an angular app, and there are two pages and I open them in each tab of browser, if I do some method in page 1, I want page 2 subscribe data change with rxjs and update data in page 2 like realtime app, is there any way to do that without websocket?, I've tried it with subscribe method but only page 1 listen that subscribe.
this is page 1 called refresh method to update boolean value

```
this.service.doRefresh();
```

page 2 listen

```
this.service.$refresh.subscribe(x=>{//boolean value changed by page 1(tab1)
    if(x) {
        console.log(x);
        this.service.stopRefresh();
    }
});
```

Comment: no each tab has its own app instance.

Comment: so,what thing i can do to make simple refresh data without websocket?

Comment: One way is to update Firebase realtime database from tab1, then tab 2 will be pushed to the update automatically.

Comment: One think that can be used without requesting backend is to use [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

Comment: There is [rx-postmessenger](https://github.com/JJWesterkamp/rx-postmessenger)

Comment: @JEY Unfortunately the browser support isn't great for BroadcastChannel yet: https://caniuse.com/#feat=broadcastchannel

Comment: @RichardMatsen That library uses `window.postMessage` which requires a reference to the window you are communicating with. With separate tabs he wont be able to do that. I believe it was intended to talk to iframes within the page or popup's spawned from it.

Comment: @bygrace the solution is to listen to event on storage as YourGoodFriend suggested.

Comment: @JEY You are right, he is my good friend ;) I knew he already solved this in his app and suggested that he provide an answer here. But I was interested in the other suggestions and wanted to bring up the drawbacks that I discovered for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @bygrace - Indeed, the lack of browser support is the killer for BroadcastChannel.

Comment: [Hubert Sablonnière: Exploring multi-screen web techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-o8B4TE18gI) describes some methods,  localStorage at about 16 minutes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can actually add event listeners to localStorage so you can use localStorage to "pass messages" between tabs

```
localStorage.setItem('yourKeyName', true)

window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
   if (event.key == 'yourKeyName'){
      //update data
   }
});
```

So when you change the value of something in localStorage on one page the other page can subscribe to the event of it changing

Browser support and more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Browser_compatibility

Comment: oke i will try it and send you guys update after try above code

Comment: @Mamen did you get a chance to try it? Let me know if you have more questions around it

Comment: yes you're correct, we can subscribe with local storage, this is npm package i used to my project `ngx-webstorage` help you guys easy to understand. thank you

Comment: Very nice and simple solution ! Thanks !