# Why angular subscription Is not working between tabs?

Tags: angular, observable

I have a simple angular app that requires users to do authentication for WebEx to receive `access_token`. I am storing the `access_token` in the local storage (simple GET api).

I am trying to create a flag/status on the level of app.component where users can tell whether they are connected/authenticated or not (meaning token did not expire).

The scenario is as follow:

1. Users login to the website
2. Users see on the top nav bar the status of their webex connection (connected/disconnected) based on whether there is a webex token stored in local storage and whether this token is expired or not.
3. If a user sees the status as "Disconnected", then s/he can request an authentication (the simple GET api I mentioned above) and receive the token. However, authentication happens in a **different tab** initiated by the application itself (meaning angular will open the auth page of the webex so users can authenticate)

The problem that I am having is that the flag/status that I created on the top nav bar is not getting updated from "Disconnected" to "Connected".

Here is what I have so far:

**myservice.ts**

```
private webexCallStatus: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  get webexStatusValue(): Observable<any> | any {
      return this.webexCallStatus.asObservable();
  }

  set webexStatusValue(data: any) {
      this.webexCallStatus.next(data);
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.webexStatusValueSubscription.add(
          this.webexStatusValueSubscription.add(
            this.globalSub.webexStatusValue.subscribe((status: string) => {
              this.webexStatus = status;
            })
          )
        );
    
        var isWebexLoggedIn = this.sharedService.isWebexLoggedIn(this.uId);
        if (isWebexLoggedIn)
          this.globalSub.webexStatusValue = 'Connected';
        else
          this.globalSub.webexStatusValue = 'Disconnected';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-chip-list class="mg-r-5">
    <mat-chip *ngIf="webexStatus == 'Connected'" class="green" selected>{{webexStatus}}</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip *ngIf="webexStatus != 'Connected'" class="red" selected>{{webexStatus}}</mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
```

**home.component.ts**

- This is where webex redirect after auth completed, it redirects to the home page
- When Webex redirects to the home page, it returns a query param `"Code"` that is used to initiate another api call to grab the `access_token`
- After the `access_token` gets stored in the local storage, the tab closes.

The status/flag on the **original page** will not understand that now the `webexStatusValue` is not "Connected" because the tab that changed `webexStatusValue` was closed. Am I doing something wrong here, I thought subscriptions travel between tabs.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.currentLoggedInUser = this.sharedService.getAccountInfo()!;
        this.uId = this.currentLoggedInUser.id;
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
          if(params?.code?.length > 0) {
            let req: WebexRequestToken = {
              grant_type: environment.webexClientGrant,
              client_id: environment.webexClientId,
              client_secret: environment.webexClientSecret,
              code: params.code,
              redirect_uri: environment.webexRedirectUrl
            };
            this.webExService.GetToken(req).subscribe((response: WebexAuthResponse) => {
              localStorage.setItem('Tempus-Webex-' + this.uId, JSON.stringify(response));
              this.globalSub.webexStatusValue = 'Connected';
              this.globalSub.setSpinnerLoadStatus(false);
              window.open('','_self')!.close();
            })
          }
        });
    }
```

Comment: make it a replaySubject `private webexCallStatus = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);`

Comment: If there is only one value to keep, the BehaviorSubject makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, then you expect the subscription which was triggered in one tab to also emit a value in the other tab.

This is simply not the case. Each tab will retrieve the angular code and work as an independent program. Therefore, subscriptions do not trigger in other tabs.

If you want them to be shared across tabs, you would need to implement a logic for that. Here is another SO question taking to that aspect: [is it possible to subscribe observable in other tab browser with rxjs angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129392/is-it-possible-to-subscribe-observable-in-other-tab-browser-with-rxjs-angular-5)

Also, you can simplify you program greatly by using a `BehaviorSubject` (https://betterprogramming.pub/what-is-a-behaviorsubject-in-rxjs-f580e934a5b2) and the `async` pipe (https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/). This could make the ngOnInit entirely unnecessary.

I don't quite understand your ngOnInit function without more context, but it does not seem correct that you call `.add(...)` and within each other. You might wanna check that.